# Do Sets exist in Go? (like in Python)

Tags: collections, set, go

Is there any Go collection similar to 'Set's in python?

alternatives:

- Is there an easy way of implementing Sets in Go?
- Is there any method to eliminate duplicates in a slice?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could just have a `map[whatevertype]bool` and set the value to `true`. You could add every element in a slice as a map key, then use a `range` to get only the unique ones back out.

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    m := make(map[string]bool)
    s := make([]string, 0)
    s = append(s, "foo")
    s = append(s, "foo")
    s = append(s, "foo")
    s = append(s, "bar")
    s = append(s, "bar")
    for _, r := range s {
        m[r] = true
    }
    s = make([]string, 0)
    for k, _ := range m {
        s = append(s, k)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", s)
}
```

Comment: I just want to add that you can actually use any arbitrary type as the value, since you don't care about it. But using a `bool` always set to true has the added benefit of being able to test if an element exists simply by indexing, because when you index a key and it does not exist, it will return the zero value for the value type, which is false for booleans.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `map[T]bool` is the best option, but another option is
`map[T]struct{}`:

```
package main

func main() {
   { // example 1
      s := make(map[string]struct{})
      s["north"] = struct{}{}
      s["south"] = struct{}{}
      _, ok := s["north"]
      println(ok)
   }
   { // example 2
      s := map[string]struct{}{
         "north": {}, "south": {},
      }
      _, ok := s["north"]
      println(ok)
   }
}
```

it's not as easy to work with, but it takes up less memory if that is a factor for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no set implementation in golang at this point. You'll need to do it yourself or get a third party lib. Also here is a nice blog post:

https://www.openmymind.net/2011/7/15/Learning-Go-By-Benchmarking-Set-Implementation/